# Opening window from cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I created a menu in CMD where depending on the option, a window would open with a specific path. I’m using the “start .” command.

I got it working to the point where I can choose an option and it will open the desired window. However, if in the same session I choose a different option, the same window will open, not a different one.
For example, if I chose option 1, a window will open at G:\Folder_1. When I choose option 2, instead of going to G:\SUBFOLDER\Folder_2, it goes to G:\Folder_1.
If I close the window, reopen the .bat file and choose option 2, it will direct me to the right folder.
How can I open different windows in the same section?

I have tried running each menu option as a different .bat file and using the start command to run the file, but it did the same thing.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
:MENU
    echo [1]Option 1
    echo [2]Option 2
    echo [3]Option 3
    echo [4]Exit

    set /p MS= Choose your option: 

        If %MS%==1 goto OPTION_1
        If %MS%==2 goto OPTION_2
        If %MS%==3 goto OPTION_3
        If %MS%==4 goto END

        :OPTION_1
        G:
        cd "Folder_1"

        Start .
        goto :Menu

        :OPTION_2
        G:
        cd SUBFOLDER
        cd Folder_2

        start .
        goto :Menu

        :OPTION_3
        G:
        cd SUBFOLDER
        cd Folder_3
        start .
        goto :Menu

        :END
        Pause
```

Comment: you may be interested in the [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is written in such a way that you start your working folder as "G:\" drive. Then when you choose option 1, you change your current folder to "G:\Folder_1". When “Start .” command is executed there, a window is opened with this path.
Now the next time you go for option 2, you should change your current folder to "G:\" according to your code. But actually you remain in "G:\Folder_1".

Relative to this path all your CD commands become invalid.

Correcting the relative paths will solve the problem.
I edited your code to change the current working directory to the root drive "G:\" every time you enter and option. So relative to the present working directory the remaining CD commands in options become valid.

Probably you may have missed "cd G:\" command while you wrote the code.

```
:MENU
echo [1]Option 1
echo [2]Option 2
echo [3]Option 3
echo [4]Exit

set /p MS= Choose your option: 

    If %MS%==1 goto OPTION_1
    If %MS%==2 goto OPTION_2
    If %MS%==3 goto OPTION_3
    If %MS%==4 goto END

    :OPTION_1
    cd G:\
    G:
    cd "Folder_1"

    Start .
    goto :Menu

    :OPTION_2
    cd G:\
    G:
    cd SUBFOLDER
    cd Folder_2

    start .
    goto :Menu

    :OPTION_3
    cd G:\
    G:
    cd SUBFOLDER
    cd Folder_3
    start .
    goto :Menu

    :END
    Pause
```

Comment: good catch. Didn't see that. Best way: use always full path like `cd /d "G:\subfolder\Folder_2"`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following method by incorporating the location into the `Start` command:

```bat
:MENU
Echo [1]Option 1
Echo [2]Option 2
Echo [3]Option 3
Echo [4]Exit

Set "MS="
Set /P "MS= Choose your option:  "

If "%MS%"=="1" GoTo OPTION_1
If "%MS%"=="2" GoTo OPTION_2
If "%MS%"=="3" GoTo OPTION_3
GoTo END

:OPTION_1
Start "" /D "G:\Folder_1" "Option 1.exe"
GoTo :Menu

:OPTION_2
Start "" /D "G:\SUBFOLDER\Folder_2" "Option 2.exe"
GoTo :Menu

:OPTION_3
Start "" /D "G:\SUBFOLDER\Folder_3" "Option 3.exe"
GoTo :Menu

:END
Pause
```

It would be better to use the `Choice` command, should your Operating Systems have it. *(Enter `Choice /?` at the Command prompt for more information).*